# online radio change playlist "on the fly"

Tags: audio-streaming, icecast

I'm trying to create online radio & stream audio with Icecast2 & Ezstream.

I currently run it via "ezstream -c config.xml"

I tried to edit the playlist file on the fly, it doesn't work without restarting the icecast.

I'm open minded to try other audio streaming servers.

Comment: It might be helpful to provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see what's wrong!

Comment: I'm using ezstream over icecast2 and executed the command "kill -SIGHUP {{ezstream_process_id}}" it refreshed the playlist only after the song finished, my mvce is "apt-get icecast2 ezstream & /etc/init.d/icecast2 start & ezstream -c config.xml"

Answer (score -1):

Try switching from ezstream to liquidsoap, it's much more flexible and it has "reload_mode" option to playlist:

http://savonet.sourceforge.net/doc-svn/reference.html#playlist